# Is there a way to specify a different config file than the default one before or after launching PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following problem.

I'm currently searching for a way to specify a different powershell.exe.config file located in some specified folder different from the folder where the powershell.exe resides in order not to overwrite the default powershell.exe.config file when starting PowerShell.

The config file I need for my purposes looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    <section name="BestMatchServiceUrlsConfig" type="Sdl.BestMatchServiceStudioIntegration.Common.UrlsConfig, Sdl.BestMatchServiceStudioIntegration.Common" />
    <section name="BestMatchServiceSettings" type="Sdl.BestMatchService.Common.Configuration.BestMatchServiceSettingsSection, Sdl.BestMatchService.Common" />
    <section name="AppStoreConfiguration" type="Sdl.AppStoreIntegration.AppStoreConfiguration, Sdl.AppStoreIntegrationPlugin" />
    <section name="CommunityNotificationsConfiguration" type="Sdl.TranslationStudio.Plugins.CommunityInside.Notifications.Configuration.CommunityNotificationsConfiguration, Sdl.TranslationStudio.Plugins.CommunityInside" />
    <section name="LanguageCloudSyncConfig" type="Sdl.TranslationStudio.LanguageCloud.Config.SyncConfigurationSection, Sdl.TranslationStudio.LanguageCloud" />
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_PInvokeStackResilience enabled="1" />
    <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
    <ThrowUnobservedTaskException enabled="true" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="icu.net" publicKeyToken="416fdd914afa6b66" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.7.0.0" newVersion="2.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.2.0" newVersion="6.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.11.0" newVersion="4.0.11.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Sdl.ApiClientSdk.Core" publicKeyToken="c28cdb26c445c888" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.3.0" newVersion="1.4.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I've already tried to run powershell.exe through the command line like this:

```
START %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe $ConfigFilePath
```

but PowerShell will get stuck in this case.

I also tried to modify the config file path after having launched PowerShell as follows:

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", $ConfigFilePath)
[Console]::WriteLine([System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE"))
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Configuration
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager].GetField("s_initState", "NonPublic, Static").SetValue($null, 0)
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager].GetField("s_configSystem", "NonPublic, Static").SetValue($null, $null)
([Configuration.ConfigurationManager].Assembly.GetTypes() | where {$_.FullName -eq "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths"})[0].GetField("s_current", "NonPublic, Static").SetValue($null, $null)
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::ConnectionStrings[0].Name
```

which sets the correct config file path, but doesn't actually use this config file. There seems to be a cache issue, e.g. a certain cache needs to be cleared first before PowerShell actually uses the specified config file. However, in my case it doesn't clear the cache or at least PowerShell still uses the default powershell.exe.config file.

Is there a way to solve this problem by either specifying directly the config file through the command line that PowerShell needs to use or after having lauched the application?

Comment: What are the settings you want to affect with your custom config?

Comment: Mot application when the path is not specified will use the config file in same folder as the app.  The app needs to be modified to use the environmental variable for the config file instead of the one in the current folder.